# VBA looping work with two workbook open and save as a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to write some CBA code to make my work easier. Actually, I want to open two workbooks, **workbook 1** and **workbook 2**.

Then I need to copy certain cells form `workbook2` (`C103:C107` for example) into `workbook 1` (`E41:E45`) and save the `workbook1` as a **new workbook** called `X1.xlsm`.

Copy (`D103:D107`) from `workbook2` and copy into (`E41:E45`) `workbook1` and save as new called `X2.xlsm`.

`(E103:E107) (workbook 2) ---(E41:E45) ( Workbook1)`, saved as `x3.xlsm`
…….

Do the same thing loop through columns of `Worbook 2`.

But the following macro does not work:

```
Sub TADDEnter()
Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim activeWB As Workbook
Dim FilePath1 As String
Dim FilePath2 As String

FilePath1 = "T:\L'Oreal\83113035 - Project Beauty\TOM\Deliverables\Tables\TADD\Copy of TADD Uploads (002).xlsx"
FilePath2 = "T:\L'Oreal\83113035 - Project Beauty\TOM\Deliverables\Tables\TADD\TADD CSV template.xlsm"
Set wbk1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath2)
Set wbk2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath1)
Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
For icol = 3 To 33
    wbk1.Sheets("DATA MEASURES FORM").Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    wbk2.Sheets("LOreal").Range(wbk2.Sheets("LOreal").Cells(103, icol), wbk2.Sheets("LOreal").Cells(107, icol)).Copy Destination:=activeWB.Sheets("DATA MEASURES FORM").Range("E41:E45")
    activeWB.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "T:\L'Oreal\83113035 - Project Beauty\TOM\Deliverables\Tables\TADD\TADD_CSV_" & wbk2.Sheets("LOreal").Cells(147, icol).Value & ".xlsm"
     activeWB.Close
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Next icol
End Sub
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Give us a clue. Mouse runs away? Monitor blows up?

Comment: What error do you get, and on which line does it highlight when you click on debug?

Comment: Try setting activeWB after you have add the new workbook. Currently, your activeWB is wbk2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the new workbook as activeWB after you have create it.

```
Sub TADDEnter()

Dim wbk1 As Workbook 'source_A
Dim wbk2 As Workbook 'source_B
Dim activeWB As Workbook 'target
Dim FilePath1 As String
Dim FilePath2 As String

FilePath1 = "T:\L'Oreal\83113035 - Project Beauty\TOM\Deliverables\Tables\TADD\Copy of TADD Uploads (002).xlsx"
FilePath2 = "T:\L'Oreal\83113035 - Project Beauty\TOM\Deliverables\Tables\TADD\TADD CSV template.xlsm"
Set wbk1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath1)
Set wbk2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath2)

For icol = 3 To 33
    wbk1.Sheets("DATA MEASURES FORM").Copy 'copy sheet and create a new workbook

    Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook 'set the new workbook as activeWB
    wbk2.Sheets("LOreal").Range(wbk2.Sheets("LOreal").Cells(103, icol), wbk2.Sheets("LOreal").Cells(107, icol)).Copy
    activeWB.Sheets("DATA MEASURES FORM").Range("E41:E45").PasteSpecial

    activeWB.SaveAs Filename:="X" & icol - 2, FileFormat:=52 '52 = xlsm
    activeWB.Close

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next icol

End Sub
```